# Sapper export failing without server

Tags: javascript, svelte, sapper

I am using [Sapper](https://sapper.svelte.dev) with [Svelte](https://svelte.dev) to create a static website.

Because my website is static, I won't be bothering with a server and will use the [`sapper export`](https://sapper.svelte.dev/docs/#Exporting) command to generate static files which I can host on GitLab pages.

I have therefore removed the `server.js` file in my `src` directory - it shouldn't be necessary. However, when I run the export command, it fails with the following error:

[image: Error: could not resolve entry module (src\server.js)]

Why is this looking for a server and how to I fix this?

I also tried removing the `server` option in `rollup.config.js`, however this now complains that the `client`, `server` and `serviceworker` properties are required.

Comment: You should not remove server.js from the src folder, Seems it is needed for the build process. Note, that it is needed for the build process, not for the site that will be built and uploaded to your server (which I assume are the files that are output to the "static" folder).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run `sapper export`, it creates the static build by running your server and crawling your site. For that reason, you *do* need server.js. (This might change in a future version.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I just realized that myself too. I think it would be handy to have the option to crawl the pages directly without a server, but at the same time, the server gives more flexibility in the future - I can just switch to a server without any further hassle. I'm really loving Svelte and Sapper so far, it's something I've wanted for many years :)